# Unable To Cancel Installation In Software Center (Matlab)

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, matlab

**A Note:** This question may be the exact same question as given in [How to cancel an installation in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151527/how-to-cancel-an-installation-in-the-software-center) but the solutions listed there haven't worked for me.

**Question:**

I am trying to terminate a software installation from Ubuntu Software Center. I tried installing `matlab-support` `0.0.17` from the software center:

> This package does not provide MATLAB. Instead, it configures an
>   existing MATLAB installation to integrate more comfortably in Debian
>   installation.

However,  **I didn't have MATLAB installed on my system** and accidentally attempted to download `matlab-support 0.0.17`. As a result, I'm facing the following problem:

Whenever I open Ubuntu Software Center, I notice that there is a process always running. It shows matlab-support 0.0.17 installing...

[image]

I look for a way to terminate the installation from the **Progress** tab to get this:

[image]

Once there, I see no way to deselect or terminate the process.

**Edit:** Output for `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

**Edit:** Output for `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  dpkg-dev libatlas3gf-base libblas-dev libblas3gf libdpkg-perl liblapack-dev liblapack3gf linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal
  linux-image-generic-lts-quantal r-base-dev r8168-dkms texinfo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

**Edit:** Output for `dpkg -l | grep matlab`
No output message:

```
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ dpkg -l | grep matlab
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$
```

**Edit:** Output for `sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  matlab-support
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 165 kB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Selecting previously unselected package matlab-support.
(Reading database ... 187961 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking matlab-support (from .../matlab-support_0.0.17_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.17) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Edit:** Output for `sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root      11060 F.... dpkg-preconfigu
```

**Edit:** Another set of commands with output `sudo kill -9 11060` and `sudo apt-get install matlab-support` :

```
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ sudo kill -9 11060
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ sudo apt-get install matlab-support
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

**Edit:** Output for `sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock` (No output message)

```
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$ sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock
[sudo] password for anirudh: 
anirudh@anirudh-Vostro-3445:~$
```

Comment: @A.B. - posted output.

Comment: added output to `dpkg -l | grep matlab`

Comment: I have a silly question... I read your post and it's not in there and I kind of assume you've tried this but have you tried `sudo apt-get remove matlab-support` perhaps? I figure you have but you didn't mention it so I might as well check to see if you tried that.

Comment: @A.B. - added output.  @KGlll I have tried `sudo apt-get purge matlab-support` to no avail.

Comment: @A.B. added output to `sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`

Comment: @A.B. - added the output for  `sudo kill -9 11060` and `start sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30474/discussion-between-a-b-and-anirudh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to find the blocking processes:

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

*Sample output*

```
USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
root      11060 F.... dpkg-preconfig
```

and

```
ps xa | grep apt
```

*Sample output*

```
24743 ? S 0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/share/apt-xapian-index/update-apt-xapian-index-dbus
```

Kill both processes

```
sudo kill -9 11060
sudo kill -9 24743
```

and your problem is solved.

The `matlab-support` is not installed, as you have identified with this command

```
dpkg -l | grep matlab
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the excact same problem with gparted. But, I saw back on the How to cancel an installation in the Software Center? question this:

```
pkill -15 dpkg
```

It worked for me, and I hope it works for you, if you have not already solved the problem.

:D