# Problem when downloading a package using Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: apt, software-center, matlab

I am trying to download the package MATLAB from Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu 14.04 , but when it begins applying the changes it does not respond. I am stuck at this point, I can not stop the procedure and it does not finish. Forcing Ubuntu Software Center to close didn't benefit. 
What is the reason for this problem? and what are the possible solutions?

I tried to write " sudo apt-get install matlab-support " in the terminal but it also wasn't helpful because it encountered errors.

Comment: "I  tried to write " sudo apt-get install matlab-support " in the terminal but it also wasn't helpful because it encountered errors." Would be really helpful if we could get those `exact` errors, no one can help you if you don't provide the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have MATLAB installed first. The package in Ubuntu software center is just the Matlab support tool. Follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/687650/18717).

Comment: I know, I have installed MATLAB 2012. In fact, I have been using the same installation recently, but yesterday I did format and reinstalled it!

Comment: Please don't link other questions on the site as your answer, without any additional information, click the flag button under the question and flag as a duplicate, so the user can be redirected there.